# VNP completeness of Permanent

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, arithmetic-circuits

Can some one suggest a good source for VNP completeness of Permanent. I tried reading it from book on Algebraic complexity theory by Burgisser,clausen,shokrollahi,lickteig. 
And What is the best known lower-bound on determinental complexity of $PERM_{n}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The place from which I had read the proof was [Completeness and Reduction in Algebraic Complexity Theory by Peter Bürgisser (.ps)](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/habil.ps). As for the determinental complexity of the permanent, the best lower bound known so far is $\Omega(n^2)$ by [Mignon and Ressayre](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.4910&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Jin Yi Cai et al have extended Mignon's result to char $p$. The basic idea is to consider Hessian but specific matrices differ.

Comment: Landsberg, Manivel, and Ressayre (http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4802) have also extended the Mignon--Ressayre result from determinantal complexity to border-determinantal complexity. (The LMR paper is fairly advanced from this point of view, but I thought I should at least mention that it was out there.)